# How to access the setLayoutDirection() method of a layout or other view element

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I'm supporting RTL based languages in my Nativescript app and would like to programmatically change the display direction of my views. Setting `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the manifest takes care of some of the standard things such as the action bar layout and some of the form inputs.

I dug through the docs and found that the `setLayoutDirection()` will accomplish this but I'm not able to get it to work on layouts (or most of the xml elements really). Here is a simple example of my failed approach

**item-list.xml**

```
  <GridLayout id="container">
    <ListView items="{{ connections }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout class='connection-li'>
                  <GridLayout class="connection-info" rows="" columns="auto, *, *" tap="">
                      <Image id="userImg" col="0" src="res://profile_gray" stretch ="none" />                        
                      <Label col="1" class="connection-name" text="{{ PatientFirstName + ' ' + PatientLastName + '.'}}" textWrap="false" />
                      <StackLayout col="2" row="1" verticalAlignment="middle" horizontalAlignment="right" height="30" width="30" tap="removeConnection">
                          <Image id="close-btn" src="res://close" stretch ="none" />             
                      </StackLayout>                                     
                  </GridLayout>                                                                         
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

**item-list.js**

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");

exports.navigatingTo = function(args) {
  var page = args.object;

  // Does not work as expected
  var container = view.getViewById(page, "container");
  container.android.setLayoutDirection(1);

  // Does work, but doesn't alter the actual page elements and layout but rather the action bar of the page. 
  page.android.setLayoutDirection(1);
}
```

`setLayoutDirection()` is apart of the `View` android class but I'm not sure how to access it from a Nativescript layout, or if it's even possible. I can't seem to find anything useful after digging into the different layout parameters. Hoping for a work around or the right approach.